# Mixins vs. Classes for Font

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm setting up fonts in a CSS style guide and would like to know what is better suited for the problem.  I've decided to either go with mixins or with classes.  I am unsure which of two is better suited?  The one will increase code in the CSS and the other will add classes on the HTML.  Both of these feel like they have a lot of repetition as well.

Mixins:

```
@mixin font-display-1 {
  font: {
    family: $font-1;
    size: 10px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}

@mixin font-display-2 {
  font: {
    family: $font-1;
    size: 12px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}

@mixin font-display-3 {
  font: {
    family: $font-2;
    size: 10px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}

...

@mixin font-display-10 {
  font: {
    family: $font-2;
    size: 16px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}
```

Classes:

```
.font-display-1 {
  font: {
    family: $font-1;
    size: 10px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}

.font-display-2 {
  font: {
    family: $font-1;
    size: 12px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}

.font-display-3 {
  font: {
    family: $font-2;
    size: 10px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}

...

.font-display-10 {
  font: {
    family: $font-2;
    size: 16px;
    weight: 300;
  }
}
```

============ EDIT ============

After reading the comments, would this be a better solution?

```
@mixin font-mixin($font, $size, $weight) {
  font: {
    family: $font;
    size: $size;
    weight: $weight;
  }
}

.font-display-1 {
  @include font-mixin($font-1, 10px, 300);
}

.font-display-2 {
  @include font-mixin($font-1, 12px, 300);
}

...

.font-display-10 {
  @include font-mixin($font-2, 16px, 300);
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not styling your headline tags instead? (H1, H2, H3, 4, H5, H6)

Comment: Repetitions when using `mixin` is DEFINITELY not the right approach. That's against the whole reason behind their existence. They're used to reduce the number of classes when they share attributes. Read this: http://wynnnetherland.com/journal/css-mixins-vs-multiple-classes/

Comment: More than 6 font, weight and size combinations.

Comment: @ShobhitSrivastava so would a combination of mixins and classes be a better approach?  Even using H1 tags, a mixin might clean up the code a little bit, I suspect.

Comment: So your focus should be to keep MINIMUM and MAINTAINABLE css. You can use whatever possible combinations. Also, keep in mind, mixins are difficult to inspect since the styles are now mixed into the rules defined